# Automapper and EFCore Join

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, automapper

I have to tables I want to Join which I can do with just EFCore but I can't figure out how to also use automapper.

So if I have two Classes

```
public class ItemVM {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int ItemName { get; set; }
    public int GroupId {get; set;}
}

public class GroupVM {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string GroupName {get; set;}
}
```

And I want to end up with:

```
public class ItemWithGroupVM {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int GroupId {get; set;}
    public string GroupName {get; set;}
}
```

So all our db fields have prefixes so in my mapping profile I have:

```
RecognizePrefixes("it");
CreateMap<Item, ItemVm>();

RecognizePrefixes("gr");
CreateMap<Group, GroupVm>();
```

Then I Run my queries:

```
var items = await _dbContext.Items.ProjectTo<ItemsVM>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToListAsync();
var groups = await _dbContext.Groups.ProjectTo<GroupsVM>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToListAsync();
```

Then I just loop through the list of items and generate a new list of ItemsWithGroupVM and set the group name string for the final output.

How can I modify my automapper profile and ef core query to do the join and the mapping without having to loop?

Comment: Add a FK property `Group` in `Item` and `ProjectTo` directly from `Item` to `ItemWithGroupVM`.